# Why Gaudiya Vaishnavas don't accept Advaita when Chaitanya Mahaprabhu accepted Sridhara Svami?

Tags: advaita, gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya

Śrī Caitanya
Mahāprabhu declared that Śrīdhara Svāmī is the authoritative commentator on
Bhāgavatam:

> prabhu hāsi’ kahe,“svāmī nā māne yei jana | veśyār bhitare tāre kariye
>   gaṇana” || eta kahi’ mahāprabhu mauna dharilā | śuniyā sabāra mane
>   santoṣa hailā ||
>
> “With a wry smile, the Lord said: “Whoever disregards the svāmī
>   (husband; or Śrīdhara Svāmī) is to be counted among the prostitutes.”
>   Mahāprabhu held silence. Everyone felt content by hearing this
>   statement.” (Caitanya-caritāmṛta
>   3.7.115-116)

Chaitanya also told:

> śrīdhara-svāmī-prasāde ‘bhāgavata’ jāni, jagad-guru śrīdhara-svāmī
>   ‘guru’ kari’ māni. śrīdhara-upare garve ye kichu likhibe
>   ‘artha-vyasta’ likhana sei, loke nā mānibe. śrīdharer anugata ye kare
>   likhana saba loka mānya kari’ karibe grahaṇa.
>
> “I understand Bhāgavatam by the grace of Śrīdhara Svāmī. I consider
>   that he, the spiritual master of the universe, is a guru. Whatever you
>   write beyond Śrīdhara out of pride would be contrary to the real
>   meaning. People would not pay attention to it. One who writes
>   following Śrīdhara’s statements will be respected by and accepted by
>   everyone.” (Caitanyacaritāmṛta 3.7.133-135)

Sridhara Svami is generally considered Advaitin and Chaitanya mahaprabhu accepted his commentary on Bhagavatam as authoritative. Then, why do Gaudiya Vaishnavas reject Advaita when Chaitanya Mahaprahu accepted Sridhara Svami's authority?

Comment: I think your Q is not clear. You didn't explain what is the connection of Svamiji with Advaita.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Sridhara Swami is generally considered Advaitin. And CMP accepted his commentary as authoritative. So people who don't know full picture often think why GV doesn't accept Advaita when CMP approved Advaita commentary and this they are confused.

Comment: Ok, I knew that thing but readers of your Q possibly do not, so it would be a good idea to tell them that thing in the Q.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the above conversation we don't get the full picture.

We get full picture of Sridhara Svami as seen by Gaudiya Vaishnavas in Tattva Sandarbha work of Jiva Goswami.

Text 27 of Tattva Sandarbha reads as follows:

> Therefore to ascertain what is actually the highest good in life we
> should focus our investigation on Srimad Bhagava-tam, carefully
> reconciling its statements with what precedes and follows them. With
> this aim, in this work consisting of six Sandarbhas the introductory
> sentences in each anuccheda] will serve the function of sutras The
> quot.ations from Srimad Bhagavatam will be the scriptural texts under
> consideration. Sridhara Svami's explanation of the Bhagavatam will
> serve as our primary commentary. Srila Sridhara Svami is a pefect
> Vaisnava. But to entice the Advaita-vadis now a days prominent all over
> Madhya-desa and other parts of the country — to become absorbed in the
> glories of the Supreme Lord, he mixed some traces of their theories
> into his writings. We will cite Sri Svamicarana s commentary verbatim
> when its agrees with the conclusions of pure Vaisnava philosophy.

Jiva Goswami quotes Sridhara Svami's explanations in most of the anucchedas of the six sandarbhas.

Śrīdhara Svāmī is considered a Vaiṣṇava because he states in his commentaries
that the Lord’s vibhūtis, abodes, qualities and forms, as well as the bodies of his
associates are eternal and that bhakti to Bhagavān is the most attractive type of
liberation. Sometimes he writes māyāvāda ideas, but it should be understood that
its purpose is to attract the māyāvādīs to bhakti, by offering bait on a hook.
Similarly pure Vaiṣṇava philosophy accepts the non-contrary parts of Sāṅkhya.
In that way, the parts of Śrīdhara Svāmī which follow pure Vaiṣṇava ideas are
quoted.

Śrīdhara Svāmī’s writings at large are not irreproachable. Rūpa Gosvāmī was
the first Gauḍīya Vaiṣṇava to point out that Śrīdhara Svāmī’s commentary on
Bhāgavatam is not perfect.

In Laghu-vaiṣṇava-toṣaṇī, Jīva Gosvāmī attacked Śrīdhara Svāmī's explanations on
several occasions (10.3.24; 10.13.57; etc.).  Still, on the whole Śrīdhara
Svāmī’s commentary on Bhāgavatam justifies Caitanya Mahāprabhu’s approval.
In many ways, he propounded the highest philosophy. For example:

> tvat-kathāmṛta-pāthodhau viharanto mahā-mudaḥ | kurvanti kṛtinaḥ kecic
> catur-vargaṁ tṛṇopamam ||
>
> “Some accomplished persons who are greatly
> joyful while sporting in the ocean of nectar topics about You render
> the four goals of life insignificant like straw.” (Bhāvārtha-dīpikā
> 10.87.21) (quoted in Bhakti-rasāmṛta-sindhu
> 1.1.40)

A brief outline of Sridhara Svami's commentary on Bhagavatam and how it clearly is far from Shankara's nondualism and comes halfway to the metaphysical nuances of acintya-bhedabheda is described in Chaitanya Vaishnava Vedanta by Ravi M Gupta.

> From a close analysis of Sridhara’s commentary on the first verse and
> four main verses of the BhAgavata, Sheridan concludes that Sridhara
> taught a “theistic non-dualism of sorts,” (ibid.: 57) not so different
> from the BhAgavata’s own bhedAbheda standpoint (ibid.: 54). While
> Sridhara employs the categories and hermeneutical tools of Advaita
> Vedanta (such as the notion of essential and accidental
> characteristics), he does not use them to defend Shankara’s radical
> nondualism. “Sridhara . . . has moved, at least in this immediate
> context, toward a non-dualism of a realistic Sankhya type, otherwise
> called ‘qualified nondualism’” (ibid.: 64). This move, Sheridan
> argues, brings him “halfway to the metaphysical nuances of
> acintya-bhedabheda” (ibid.: 58). Perhaps the clearest evidence of
> Sridhara’s shift lies in his avoidance of the concept of mAyA (the
> illusory power that comprises this world) as delineated in Advaita
> Vedanta. For Sridhara, mAyA does not consist of ignorance (avidyA)
> that results from the superimposition (adhyAsa) of the world on
> Brahman. Instead, it is the veiling, multi-faceted sakti of the
> Supreme Lord, understood in terms similar to mAyA in theistic
> Vaisnavism. In his commentary on the BhAgavata’s first verse, Sridhara
> Svami fails to make any mention of the concepts of superimposition,
> confusion (bhrama), or ignorance, despite ample opportunities to do
> so. The word “nirasta-kuhakam” is glossed simply as “nirasta| kuhaka|
> kapaVa| mAyAlak2aWam yasmi|s tam”—“him in whom the deceit that is
> characteristic of mAyA is destroyed.” Even the line “tejo-vAri-m{dAm .
> . . ,” which Jiva Gosvami himself recognizes as having potential for
> an Advaita interpretation, is let off quite gently by 3rcdhara. He
> interprets vinimaya as vyatyaya, the false appearance of one element
> in another, like a mirage seen on a hot surface, water seen in glass,
> and glass appearing like water. Although these examples are typically
> Advaitic in nature, Sridhara does not take the opportunity to develop
> a theory of error. This is especially significant given the fact that
> Shankara’s Brahmasutra commentary begins straight away with a theory of
> super-imposition. For Sridhara, the essential point here is that
> despite appearances, the world finds its basis in the true reality of
> Brahman, who has the power to dispel all confusion. We find another
> example of Sridhara’s reticence in regard to mAyA in his commentary on
> the second verse of the four-verse Bhagavata. Sheridan translates the
> verse and commentary as follows: What is manifest without a basis and
> is not manifest in the Self, know that to be the maya of the Self,
> like an appearance, like a shadow. [Sridhara’s commentary:] This
> defines maya since it was mentioned subsequently and since the linking
> of maya and Self follows maya. “Without basis” means without a
> substantial basis. For this reason, what is implicit in the substratum
> of the Self appears real “and also does not appear,” know that to be
> the maya of the Self. “Like an appearance” means the two moons etc.
> which are not distinguished in perception. “Like a shadow” means the
> non-recognition of something that is. The shadow is Rahu which remains
> in the realm of the planets, even if it is not seen. (1994: 59–60)
> As in his explanation of the BhAgavata’s first verse, Sridhara here is
> satisfied to describe mAyA simply in terms of false appearances, using
> examples found in the verse itself. Also as in the first verse, he is
> primarily interested in the fact that the world of appearances has a
> real basis in the reality of Brahman. As such, he makes no attempt to
> go beyond the text of the BhAgavata to articulate a theory of
> ignorance in Advaitic terms. Indeed, Sridhara was perhaps closer to
> the Caitanya Vaisnava view of sakti than he was to Advaitic concepts
> of mAyA. A more positive articulation of Sridhara Svami’s views on
> mAyA can be found in his commentary on verse 1.7.6 of the BhAgavata.
> This verse appears in a description of Vyasa’s state of trance before
> he composed the PurAna, which, we have seen, is one of Jiva’s main
> loci for finding the overall meaning of the BhAgavata. As such, Jcva
> discusses this verse at length in the Tattva-sandarbha (from section
> 32 to 45). He sees in it the possibility of nondualist interpretation
> and so takes the opportunity to argue against the Advaita ideas of
> mAyA, ignorance (avidyA), and limitation (upAdhi). Yet Sridhara’s
> commentary on this verse is remarkably simple, positive, and free of
> heavyweight Advaita terminology: The learned (Vyasa) composed the
> sAtvata-sa|hitA [BhAgavata PurAna] for people who do not know
> bhakti-yoga for Adhoksaja, which directly removes unwanted things.
> [Sridhara’s commentary] This is stated: The Lord, who possesses all
> saktis, who knows everything, who has an eternally manifest, supremely
> blissful form (svarupa), controls mAyA by his knowledge- sakti. The
> living entity, whose true form is unmanifest, and who (instead)
> possesses qualities just opposite to it, is bewildered by his (the
> Lord’s) mAyA. The living entity is liberated through knowledge that is
> obtained by bhakti to the Lord. That is stated by Visnusvami, “The
> Lord, who is eternal, cognizant and blissful, is embraced by knowledge
> (sa|vit) and the energy of bliss. The living entity is covered by his
> own ignorance and is pained by masses of suffering.” So also, “He who
> controls mAyA is the Lord, and he who is pained by her is the living
> entity. We praise this Man-lion Lord, who continually enjoys with his
> own mAyA. He possesses transcendental bliss that is manifested from
> himself, and from him the world of great suffering is manifested. He
> is unsullied by the fear born from the differences of the world, which
> has arisen from his own glance.” **And so on Here we find nearly all
> the elements of the Caitanya Vaisnava concept of Bhagavan’s sakti.** The
> Lord is the possessor of all energies and his form is not temporary or
> material, but a manifestation of his personal sakti, with which he
> forever enjoys. He does, however, remain aloof from the external
> energy, which comprises the world of mAyA. As a transformation of the
> Lord’s sakti, mAyA is not false or illusory in itself, but only in its
> effect on the hapless living entity. Its influence can be annulled by
> devotion to Bhagavan. Although Sridhara Svami does not partition
> Bhagavan’s sakti into three types, clearly all the elements necessary
> for the development of a more systematic theory are present above.
> Furthermore, the verse from Visnusvami provides the basis for a
> further division of the internal energy into three parts. The only
> element of the sakti concept that is missing—indeed, conspicuous by
> its absence—is inconceivability (acintya). The strong emphasis on the
> inconceivable nature of Bhagavan’s energies seems to be a distinctly
> Caitanya Vaisnava proclivity, arising from a desire to preserve
> Bhagavan’s transcendence. We may thus confirm Sheridan’s assessment of
> Sridhara as “halfway to the metaphysical nuances of
> acintya-bhedabheda” (1994: 58). A much more comprehensive and in-depth
> study of Sridhara’s commentaries would be required to reach any broad
> conclusions about his views. Whatever the outcome of such a study
> might be, however, it is clear that he cannot be simplistically
> aligned with, or assigned to, Advaita Vedanta.

Chaitanya's preference may just as well have been a result of appreciation for Sridhara's deep
devotion or his bhedAbheda theology not necessarily because of his Advaita affiliation, which, we have argued, is a more
accurate characterization of Sridhara's views than is pure Advaita. Also, we find Sridhara’s commentary on BhAgavata 10.43.17,
where we find the seeds of a bhakti–rasa theory centered on Krishna which is important thing in Chaitanya Vaishnavism.

From incidents of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu with Prakasananda Sarasvati and Sarvabhouma Bhattacharya, it is clear that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu didn't accept advaita. So no way he would accept Sridhara Svami's advaitic explanations whenever it was seen. And also it could be that he didn't criticize Sridhara Svami because he is considered vaishnava who wrote some advaitic explanations on purpose. Most important verse of Gaudiya Vaishnavism SB 1.3.28 is differently explained by Sridhara Svami who just says Krishna is Narayana himself. So it can't be 100% acceptance of Sridhara Svami's comments by Chaitanya Mahaprabhu. But since Sridhara Svami closely gives vaishnava conclusions most of the times, he is accepted as an authority. And Jiva Goswami follows Sridhara Svami's explanations whenever they agreement with pure Vaishnava siddhanta only. Whenever he quoted Sridhara Svami's commentary, he mentioned his name or tika ca which means Sridhara's commentary says and whenever he doesn't agree with Sridhara's advaitic interpretation, out of respect for Sridhara, Jiva does not quote him, paraphrase him, or even use language similar to his. As far as the reader is concerned, the opposing views could have come from any Advaitin.

Thus, Gaudiya Vaishnavas followed Sridhara Svami and had great reverence for him  mostly because most of the his commentary is in line with pure Vaishnava philosophy, but whenever he offers an advaitic explanation, Gaudiya Vaishnavas didn't accept that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92191/discussion-on-answer-by-krishna-varna-why-gaudiya-vaishnavas-dont-accept-advait).

Answer (score 1):

Sripad Sridhar Swami is not considered Advaitin in Gaudiya Vaishnava Sampradaya.  Sripad Swamipaad is Considered as a Pure Mahabhagvat Vaishnav Acharya who have pure Vaishnav Doctrines in his work however he appeared in a very sensitive time period when Advait had huge influnce so he in order to attract Advaitins sometimes Added some Advait Doctrines in his work but he was a hidden Vaishnav with a Mission.      That's why Mahaprabhu, Srila Rupa Goswami, Srila Jiva Goswami, Srila Vishwanath Chakravarti Thakur, Srila Baladev Vidyabhushan, Srila Bhaktisiddhant Sarasvati Thakur, Srila AC Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupad and all Gaudiya Vaishnava Acharyas and everyone accepts his Authority.     Acc to Srila Bhaktisiddhant Sarasvati Thakur Prabhupad works Srila Sridhar Swami belonged to the Vishnuswami Rudra Sampradaya as his aparent from His Commentries Philosophy and his Glorification of Lord Shiva in his work and many other Factors but acc to time Place and Circumstance was living outwardly as an Advaitin.

Gaudiya Vaishnavas are strong critics of Advait Vedant.  Caitanya Mahaprabhu himself Defeated in Debate Srila Sarvabhaum Bhattacharya in Jagannath Puri and Srila Prakshananda Sarasvati and his followers in Kashi who belonged to Sankaracharya Advait Sampradaya and Brought them into Gaudiya Vaishnava Sampradaya.

Caitanya Mahaprabhu said "Mayavadi Bhashya Sunile hoye Sarvanash" - "Even by hearing Mayavadi Philosophy one will surely lead to destruction".

Sri Caitanya Mahaprabhu accepted Diksha in the Parampara of Srila Madhvacharya.  This is written in Works of Srila Hariram Vyas ji (Contemporary of Mahaprabhu belonging to Same Shakha of Sampradaya), Srila Kavi Karnapura (One of Mahaprabhu Shiksha Disciple and took Diksha from one of the 6 Goswamis), Srila Gopal Guru Goswami, Srila Narahari Chakravarti Thakur, Srila Baladev Vidyabhushan, Srila Bhaktivinod Thakur, Srila Bhaktisiddhant Sarasvati Thakur and Srila AC Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupad.   This is also accepted by many Bonafide Gaudiya Vaishnava Traditional lines and their Acharyas like Sri Pundrik Goswami Ji of Radha Raman Parivaar.    Even Madhva Sampradaya Acharyas also accept the Common lineage of Gaudiya and Madhva Sampradaya.    Although we have a Shakha Bhed but Overall everything is common with certain Differences in Philosophy.

Hare Krishna

Comment: Those who are not intelligent will say foolish things that its mayavadi. lol.